# ps shows my mkdir command with a space where I had a slash

Tags: ps, automounting, mkdir

I have a script that I ran which seemed to hang during a `mkdir` command.  The command is of the form:

```
mkdir -p /a/b/c/d
```

However, in the `ps` results, I see:

```
mkdir -p /a/b c/d
```

What could cause this space to have appeared in the ps results?

As potentially helpful (or distracting) information, `/a/b` is an auto-mounted location, which is currently not working properly.  The script works fine (creating directories in the right place) when the auto mount is working properly.  My goal here is to handle the error condition properly and to understand what ps and/or mkdir is doing adding a space.  Does anybody know?

Comment: I am not to sure why that space is being injected, but I would just wrap it in quotes to ensure no weird escaping is needed: `mkdir -p "/a/b/c/d"`